# PHP get_object_vars not working

Tags: php, laravel

Function should return array

```
public static function categories() {
    // return array of categories
    $categories = Category::select('category')->get();
    return get_object_vars($categories);
}
```

However, when I dump `categories()` I get `array(0) { }`

**Categories Table**

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |       category       |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | Appliances           |
| 2  | Auto Parts           |
| 3  | Boats & Watercraft's |
| 4  | Campers              |
+----+----------------------+
```

When I return `$categories` I get a longer version of this

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#272 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(20) { [0]=> object(Category)#289 (20) { ["table":protected]=> string(10) "categories" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["category"]=> string(10) "Appliances" } ["original":protected]=> array(1) { ["category"]=> string(10) "Appliances" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> object(Category)#288 (20) { ["table":protected]=> string(10) "categories" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["category"]=> string(10) "Auto Parts" } ["original":protected]=> array(1) { ["category"]=> string(10) "Auto Parts" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) } [2]=> object(Category)#271 (20) { ["table":protected]=>
```

Comment: It's not `get_object_vars not working`, it's your query returns nothing.

Comment: What is `->get()` returning?

Comment: did u var_dump your $categories ? what type is it ?

Comment: if I return `$categories` I get a very big object from eloquent

Comment: @Rafael Most of you're property's are `protected`, so try to add a function in your class and call the function in the class and not from outside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_object_vars` doesn't work correctly because it can only find actual (and accessible) properties. A `Collection` (which is what `$categories` is) has no properties that can be read. What you probably want to do is `lists()`

```
$categories = Category::lists('category');
return $categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your property's aren't public!

If you look into the manual you will see it why: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

In German a quote (Which makes it more clear):

> Liefert die öffentlichen Elemente eines Objekts

Translated: (Returns the public elements of a object)

So also a example in the manual how you can get all your property's:

```
<?php

class foo {
    private $a;
    public $b = 1;
    public $c;
    private $d;
    static $e;

    public function test() {
      var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

$test = new foo;
var_dump(get_object_vars($test));

$test->test();

?>
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
  ["c"]=>
  NULL
}
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  NULL
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
  ["c"]=>
  NULL
  ["d"]=>
  NULL
}
```

As you can see from the example of the manual you won't get any property's from the class which aren't public, so you can add a function in the class which will return every property

Comment: What is the point to put a German quote actually? Actually "Returns the public elements of a object" is not correct.

Comment: @zerkms In the english version the text is: `Gets the properties of the given object` so there you can't really see that this only get's the public property's, if you call it outside of the class

Comment: Because it's not only public are returned - see the example you copied, the second dump contains not only public members